# Weight to Volume conversion considering Density. How?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I have found a calculator online that does exactly what I need it to do. It calculates Weight to Volume based on Density. I would like to know if anyone could help me find out what formula they use in order to obtain the same results in Excel.

Here's the link: [Weight to Volume Calculator](http://www.onlineconversion.com/weight_volume_cooking.htm)

Here are is some sample data and expected output:

**Substance** = Leave Blank 
**Density** - 1.099 g/cm3 
**Convert What Quantity** = 250 
**From this** = milligram 
**To This** = milliliter

**Result (Rounded to 3 decimal places)** 
[250 milligram = 0.227 milliliter]

Comment: This are simple math calculations. 0.25g * 1.099g/cm³ = ~0.227479526842584 cm³ while 1cm³ = 1mL (1L = 1dm³)

Comment: K. I get 0.274 with your formula. The calculator shows 0.227. Thoughts?

Comment: you are right... that is a typo... it is divided and not multiplied :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1cm3 = 1 ml
1g = 1000 mg
```

so the formula in this particular case would be:

```
=round((weight / 1000) / density, 3)
```